# Displaying UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios7.1

I'm trying to display a button to the view programmatically with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
_detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_detailButton.frame =  CGRectMake(23, 294, 72, 37);
[_detailButton setTitle:@"UIButton!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_detailButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(showPop:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:_detailButton];

}
```

I have the button declared in the .h file like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *detailButton;
```

The code does not throw any errors or warnings, but when I run there is no button displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I check your code in my project its working fine i think in your case there are some other view that cover this button so check that your code has no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your button probably covered by another view. Just make sure its on top of other views.

In `viewWillAppear` add the following line of code:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.detailButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your button's type is of `UIButtonTypeCustom`, the button's default title color is white, so you can't see it if your view's background color is white.

```
[_detailButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Why? the button has title, so I think you can see the button by it's title

Comment: @Basheer_CAD You're right. The button's title color needs to be set to black so that you can see it. I'll edit my answer.